# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found - cant find the typo Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to the laravel framework. I tried to pass data from the database to my view but it gives me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.aanvragens' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `aanvragens`).

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Aanvragen;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class aanvragenController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

            $aanvragen = Aanvragen::all();

            return view('aanvragen.index', compact('aanvragen'));

    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/overzicht', 'aanvragenController@index')->name('aanvragen.index');
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Aanvragen extends Model
{

}
```

I know my database connection is working as I can migrate my migrations (the default ones). What is strange to me is that I can't recall I typed `aanvragens` somewhere. Not in my controller, view, model etc. My database table name is `aanvragen`. Is there someone who can help me? Maybe I forgot to include something or made a typo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal convention, singular model names, and plural table names.

You can override this in your model.

`public $table = 'aanvragen'`

Comment: So everytime I try to fetch data from my database I have to specify the table name in my model? It worked anyway but I am just curious. Thanks :)